# Null Reference when submitting Umbraco Forms to custom data source

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-forms

I'm trying to make **Umbraco Forms** (Umbraco v7.5.3) save to my own data source.
I followed this guide: http://www.nibble.be/?p=84

And it appears to work-ish. I can connect and generate a form based on the table. Which is nice.

### My setup

1. I add a new forms data source with the connection string:

   ```
   Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;
   ```
2. My table looks like this:

   [image: table]

   The Id (PK) property is configured as Identity
3. I choose some fields I want to use in the form:

   [image: field selection]
4. I choose which data types it should use:

   [image: field types]

   I'm a bit puzzled why the `Id` field is there. I didn't select it, and the guide I followed didn't have this field either :/?
5. It generates this form for me:

   [image: generated form]

### Error

But when I try to submit form data I get the following error. Which isn't nice.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Umbraco.Forms.Core.Providers.DatasourceTypes.MsSql.InsertRecord(Record
>   record) +1750
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Services.RecordService.storeRecord(Record record,
>   Form form) +1574
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Services.RecordService.Approve(Record record, Form
>   form) +343    Umbraco.Forms.Web.Services.RecordService.Submit(Record
>   record, Form form) +565
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Controllers.UmbracoFormsController.SubmitForm(Form
>   form, FormViewModel model, Dictionary`2 state, ControllerContext
>   context) +2245
>
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Controllers.UmbracoFormsController.GoForward(Form
>   form, FormViewModel model, Dictionary`2 state) +205
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Controllers.UmbracoFormsController.HandleForm(FormViewModel
>   model, Boolean captchaIsValid) +785    lambda_method(Closure ,
>   ControllerBase , Object[] ) +143
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9765121    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

### Questions

- Why is the `Id` field added to my form when I didn't select it?
- How is the form linked to my table? When I create a new form I cannot set a data source for it, and I cannot find any config on the generated form that points to my data source.

  - How are form fields linked to a table column? Is it via the "display name"?
- Why do I get the above `Null Reference` when trying to submit my form?

Comment: Did you work this out?

Comment: I wrote on their forum and it seems that I ran into a bug with their Forms module. So I concluded that it wasn't production ready and abandoned Umbraco

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by upgrading the version of Umbraco Forms. I guess this was a known issue for Umbraco v7.4.3 and Umbraco Forms v4.3.2, which are the versions I was using.

See this issue report: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/CON-1188